# How does Fluent NHibernate manage to get a reference to a property using that weird delegates?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

For instance, if I want to map property Title I use:

```
> Map(x => x.Title);
```

That's weird because this delegate is only returning the **value** of the property and not the property itself while NHibernate needs to know the **property** itself.

How does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map is a function, that (among other things via overloads) takes a `Expression<Func<T>>` - i.e. it looks like a `Func<T>`, but `Expression<Func<T>>` gets converted into an expression tree instead of just the lambda.

Expression trees are basically ASTs, and you can write code to traverse an expression tree to extract a string with the property name, allowing you to reflect "normally" from then on.

There's a lot of stuff available where people write stuff that reflect on expression trees. Check out [this post](http://ivanz.com/2009/12/04/how-to-avoid-passing-property-names-as-strings-using-c-3-0-expression-trees/) for example, for a demonstration on how to write a couple of utility methods to make the reflection easy.

Comment: Thank you mookid. I'm gonna look at Expression Trees to understand it better.